# TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a chatApp in ReactJS but I am experiencing this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

I have called "printmessage" but still it is still returning null. (on line 144)
**APP.JS:**

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBTwRj0vzQn4v-IRvRQ7UQSPMnBNT0Gi0A",
  authDomain: "whatapp-02.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://whatapp-02-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "whatapp-02",
  storageBucket: "whatapp-02.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1085780260212",
  appId: "1:1085780260212:web:540d871a14bb7536b4e821"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ' ',
      partner: ' ',
      key: ' ',
      allkey: ' ',
      message: ' ',
      prevmessage: ' ',
      username: ' ',
      partnermessage: ' ',
      chatpartner: ' ',
    };
  }

  login=()=>{
    var key = Math.random().toString().substring(2, 8);
    this.setState({key: key,});
    firebase.database().ref('USER-'+key).set({
      key: key,
      partner: ' ',
    });
    document.getElementsByClassName("logindiv")[0].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName("chatdiv")[0].style.display = "block";
    setInterval(this.update_partner, 1000)
  }

  get_user=()=>{
    var parsedallkey = parseInt(this.state.key,10) + parseInt(this.state.partner,10);
    var input = prompt("enter user code:")
    firebase.database().ref('USER-'+this.state.key).set({
     partner: input,
    });
    firebase.database().ref('USER-'+input).set({
      partner: this.state.key,
    });
    this.setState({allkey: parsedallkey})
  }
   
  update_partner=()=>{
  var parsedallkey = parseInt(this.state.key,10) + parseInt(this.state.partner,10);
  firebase.database().ref('USER-'+this.state.key).once('value', (snapshot)=>{
    var partner = snapshot.val().partner
    this.setState({partner: partner})
  })
  this.setState({allkey: parsedallkey})
  setInterval(this.identify_message, 2000) 
  }

  handle_message=(e)=>{
   this.setState({message: e.target.value});
   console.log(this.state.message)
  }

  send_message=()=>{
    firebase.database().ref('MESSAGE'+this.state.allkey).push().set({ //Save user name and message in reference "messages" in firebase database
        sender: this.state.key,
        message: this.state.message
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (<>
     <div className='logindiv'>
     <h1 style={{float: 'left'}}>chatApp</h1>
       <a href="#" role="button" onClick={this.login} style={{position:'relative',top:29,float: 'right'}}>Guest login</a>
     <div style={{position: 'relative', top:90,height:440, textAlign: 'center', backgroundImage: "url(https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/20/74/x58BEZ.jpg)"}}>
       <h2 style={{position: 'relative',top:50,color: 'white'}}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec dapibus sapien, quis sagittis quam. Pellentesque lacus mi, bibendum ac augue non, placerat tempus justo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Morbi laoreet tellus consequat pulvinar pulvinar. Cras neque ante, varius vel feugiat nec, cursus nec sapien. Sed <br></br>viverra ullamcorper accumsan. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc vitae pellentesque lectus. Vivamus eget urna at tellus porta sodales at quis urna. <br></br>Aliquam non enim non ipsum viverra gravida a convallis metus. Aenean dapibus accumsan nunc, non vestibulum nulla semper ut. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur commodo posuere ligula id varius. Morbi rutrum eu arcu sit amet viverra. Vestibulum hendrerit sodales eros eget imperdiet.</h2>
     </div>
     </div>

     <div className='chatdiv'>
<div>
  {/* Navbar */}
  <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    {/* Container wrapper */}
    <div className="container-fluid">
      {/* Navbar brand */}
      <h4 className="navbar-brand" >Your key: {this.state.key}</h4>
      {/* Toggle button */}
      {/* Collapsible wrapper */}
      <div className id>
        {/* Search form */}
        <form className="d-flex input-group w-auto ml-auto">
          <input type="search" className="form-control align-self-center" placeholder=" Enter a user code..." aria-label="Search" />
          <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark" onClick={this.get_user}>
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      {/* Collapsible wrapper */}
    </div>
    {/* Container wrapper */}
  </nav>
  {/* Navbar */}
  <div className="copntainer-fluid">
    <div className>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlTextarea3" />
        <ul id="printmessage"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form className="d-flex input-group w-auto ml-auto">
      <input type="search" className="form-control align-self-center" placeholder=" Enter your message..." aria-label="Search" />
      <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" onClick={this.send_message} data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">
        Send
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


     </div>
  </>);
  }

  identify_message=()=>{
    firebase.database().ref('MESSAGE'+this.state.allkey).limitToLast(1).on("child_added", (snapshot)=>{
      if(snapshot.val().sender + ": " + snapshot.val().message + ' , you said' === this.state.prevmessage || this.state.partnermessage === snapshot.val().sender + ": " + snapshot.val().message + ' , he said'){}else{
      if(snapshot.val().sender === this.state.key){
        var li = document.createElement("li")
        li.innerHTML = snapshot.val().sender + ": " + snapshot.val().message + ' , you said'; 
        console.log(snapshot.val().sender + ": " + snapshot.val().message + ' , you said')
        console.log(this.state.allkey)
        this.setState({prevmessage: snapshot.val().sender + ": " + snapshot.val().message + ' , you said'})
        document.getElementById("printmessages").appendChild(li)
      }else if(snapshot.val().sender === this.state.partner){
          var li = document.createElement("li")
          li.innerHTML = snapshot.val().sender + ": " + snapshot.val().message + ' , he said';
          document.getElementById("printmessages").appendChild(li)
          console.log(snapshot.val().sender + ": " + snapshot.val().message + ' , he said')
          this.setState({partnermessage: snapshot.val().sender + ": " + snapshot.val().message + ' , he said'})
      }
    }
   });
  }


}

export default App;
```

I am using React-CLI. I have also integrated bootstrap using CDN in public/index.html.

Comment: Where is the element with the id `printmessages`?

Comment: @tomerpacific at line 118.  in div "form-group"

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but, as a side note, your entire code has very little to do with React and should be fundamentally changed if you want to do things "the React way". You should not interact directly with the DOM; all those `document.getElementById()`, `document.getElementsByClassName()`, `document.createElement()`, etc. somehow "defeat" the very purpose of using React.

Comment: @secan What do you mean?

Comment: He means that it should be React rendering your HTML, not you using the `createElement`. Anyway, seems like in your code there is no element with id `printmessages`. At least in the post

Comment: @luissmg it's printmessage (not printmessages)

Comment: But your code looks for the other one: `document.getElementById("printmessages").appendChild(li)`

Comment: No problem. I also left an answer with it explained

Comment: @SK4 I mean that you are importing React in your code but you are not using it (well, you are using some of it but a minimal part). If you wanted to do the same with plain JavaScript, your code would have not looked very different.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in you DOM search. You are looking for the element with id `printmessages` that doesn't exist instead of looking for the list element, which id is `printmessage`. You just need to change the `document.getElementById` to look for the correct element like this:

```
document.getElementById("printmessage").appendChild(li)
```

Also, as said in the comment, this has little to do with React since you are the one rendering the content. You should manage to find a way to "append" the content inside the component with a method.